# How to connect Magento admin to Venia theme PWA storefront?

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

I setup vue storefront venia theme and working fine. Now I am trying to connect magento admin to venia storefront but not working.

**Note**: Venia theme working fine and I want to connect Magento admin.

Please guide me if anyone setup this before and have proper solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help you. It is working for me.

Please update magento URL **MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL** then run below command

> MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/" 
> CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN="sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk" 
> yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept

I follow magento doc https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

**Note**: Please run indexer and cache clean command.

Comment: Yes Its Awsome Solution And Perfetly Working For me

Comment: Thanks @SurajPrajapat it's my pleasure.